# 3D component animation in Swing

Tags: java, swing, 3d, geometry

I work in Swing, and I have the following requirement.

**Requirement:** a 3D sphere revolving in a `JInternalFrame` (`JPanel` or similar), with buttons & labels revolving in a concentric symmetrical fashion around the sphere. Each of the buttons when clicked take me to a different screen.

**Question:** Is there a 3D API which after some "banging wall" at least enables me to meet the requirement?